# jQuery - preventDefault() loading page

Tags: jquery

I thought I had this but stuck on last thing.

I have an updated jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/Q73Nd/8/

I want to

1. Load the thumbnails.
2. Start slideshow.
3. Stop and Start buttons to stop and start slideshow.
4. Click thumbnail and slideshow loads to that image.

I'm stuck on the last point - if I click the thumbnail it loads the image in a new window.

```
    $('thumbs a').click(function(e){
      bigImg.attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
      e.preventDefault();
    })
```

Why does it load the image in a new window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `#` to target `div` with id `thumbs`:

```
$('#thumbs a').click(function(e){
    bigImg.attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q73Nd/10/)

Comment: Thanks, somedays it's just not your day

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct. I think that you mean `.thumbs` and not `thumb`.

```
$('.thumbs a').click(function(e){
    bigImg.attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
})
```